# Access denied while creating managed metadata navigation

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I'm trying to implement our site's global navigation using managed metadata, but I keep getting some access denied problems despite I'm already the Site Collection and TermStore administrator.

What kind of access am i missing?

[image: Error - office 365 access denied creating termset]

Even if I manually create a termset used for navigation, I get an access denied page when I try to associate it with the navigation.

Answer (score -2):

Old question but it might help... http://www.sharepointappie.nl/confusing-access-denied-managing-navigation-office365/

Comment: Can you take out the main points from the article and place them in your answer?  Use the link as a reference, not the standalone answer.